# Ignore folder or file for Node Azure Function App

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-functions

I want my Node.js Azure Function App to ignore a test data file.
When I run my app, after adding the file, I see it trying to parse the file and showing the following error:

> Worker was unable to load function ...

How do I tell the runtime to ignore this data file or the folder containing it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I Know,

> Worker was unable to load function ...

This error comes when any packages installed outside of root `node_modules` folder and if those are not included in the runtime or deployment.

> How do I tell the runtime to ignore this data file or the folder containing it?

`.gitignore` file plays major role in Azure Functions that used to ignore the specified files even they have changes.

[image]